# go-lang project folder structure convention

Tags: go

I just wanted to confirm my understanding of a typical project folder structure in a Go project, which follows the [Go tool conventions](http://golang.org/doc/code.html).

If i'm writing a package called `my-package`, which uses another 3rd party external package - `other-package`. Then based on conventions, is this directory structure correct ?

```
+bin
+pkg
+src
  |
  --- my-package.com/..
  |
  --- external-package.com/..
```

The reason I ask this again after reading the docs is because unlike other language conventions, the user and 3rd party code are in the same top level folder.

Comment: Pwd of my dir structure: ```/go/src/github.com/github-account-name/project-name```

Comment: yes that's fine as long as the root is $GOPATH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*via irc #go-nuts*

A user's machine will have a common `$GOPATH/src` for all projects. This `$GOPATH/src` could have multiple projects (user's, external packages etc.) there. The user would just commit the `$GOPATH/src/mypackage` to their src repo.

If you want to have separate directories for your src, and 3rd party package source, then prepend another path to `$GOPATH`. `go get` will download the 3rd party packages to that path. `go-get` downloads 3rd packages to the first path it finds in the array of paths specified by `$GOPATH`.

Answer (score 1):

Golang is so diferent to other languages with respect this topic, I can say that in my firts days with Golang was hard to understand this topic. I recommend you to have all the proyects on   $GOPATH/src and dont have more that one $GOPATH.

On GOLANG we have to adapted to it, like sa http://golang.org/doc/code.html (Code organization)

Comment: how do then imports look like for your custom packages? e.g you have your  project in `/src/project1` and some helper package is under `/src/project1/helper`. Do you have to do `import "project1/myhelper"`? It seems to me it would be much cleaner if `project1` keyword could be omitted (and this would happen if this was our only project in `src` folder as we'd just remove `project1` and move all other files and folder one level up). Can we do this anyways somehow (while still having multiple projects)?